# sstableloader fails with NoHostAvailableException, "All host(s) tried for query failed"

Tags: cassandra

sstableloader run on a v4.1.3 host using sstablefiles from a v3.11.6 host:

```
sstableloader -v --nodes oneofthehosts --username whatever --password whatever --truststore /etc/cassandra/conf/truststore.jks --truststore-password whatever --keystore /etc/cassandra/conf/keystore.jks --keystore-password whatever /tmp/keyspace/table
```

The (slightly trimmed) error message:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: oneofthehosts/someip:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [oneofthehosts/someip:9042] Operation timed out))
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialise org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeSSTableLoaderClient
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeSSTableLoaderClient.init(NativeSSTableLoaderClient.java:102)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:167)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:91)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:58)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: oneofthehosts/someip:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: oneofthehosts/someip:9042] Operation timed out))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:270)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:109)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.negotiateProtocolVersionAndConnect(Cluster.java:1813)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1726)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:214)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:387)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:366)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:311)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeSSTableLoaderClient.init(NativeSSTableLoaderClient.java:70)
    ... 3 more
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialise org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeSSTableLoaderClient
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:104)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:58)
```

Some selected messages after setting TRACE level in logback-tools.xml:

```
DEBUG 13:29:19,765 [oneofthehosts/someip:9042] preparing to open 1 new connections, total = 1
DEBUG 13:29:19,915 Connection[oneofthehosts/someip:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] Connection established, initializing transport
TRACE 13:29:19,920 Connection[oneofthehosts/someip:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false], stream 0, writing request STARTUP {CQL_VERSION=3.0.0, DRIVER_VERSION=3.11.0, DRIVER_NAME=DataStax Java Driver}
DEBUG 13:29:20,113 [id: 0xef0b330f, L:/someip:44896 - R:oneofthehosts/someip:9042] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

waiting for timeout

TRACE 13:29:32,027 Defuncting Connection[oneofthehosts/someip:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false]
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.OperationTimedOutException: [oneofthehosts/someip:9042] Operation timed out
DEBUG 13:29:32,028 [oneofthehosts/someip:9042] preventing new connections for the next 1000 ms
DEBUG 13:29:32,029 [oneofthehosts/someip:9042] Connection[oneofthehosts/someip:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] failed, remaining = 0
DEBUG 13:29:32,029 Connection[oneofthehosts/someip:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=true] closing connection
DEBUG 13:29:32,029 Not terminating Connection[oneofthehosts/someip:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=true]: there are still pending requests
DEBUG 13:29:32,031 Connection[oneofthehosts/someip:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=true], stream 0, Error writing request STARTUP {CQL_VERSION=3.0.0, DRIVER_VERSION=3.11.0, DRIVER_NAME=DataStax Java Driver}
DEBUG 13:29:32,035 [Control connection] error on oneofthehosts/someip:9042 connection, no more host to try
```

Does this look familiar? Could it be TLS related or are we beyond initial connection setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The embedded Java driver used by `sstableloader` is unable to connect to the cluster leading to the `NoHostAvailableException`. The underlying `OperationTimedOutException` indicates that the driver didn't get a response from the server at all.

I agree with your assessment that it is related to TLS so I recommend that you validate the TLS details you've provided on the command line. Make sure you're using the credentials for the Cassandra 4.1 cluster. Cheers!